# Explain the choice of the verb "dip" in "dip your lights"

Tags: meaning, verbs, idioms, meaning-in-context

Does the phrase "dip your lights" mean to turn them off or something else? Why is the word *dip* used?

Quote:

> If you drive with your headlights on full beam in fog, the light will just reflect back on you. Dip your lights — it will be much easier to see.

Comment: I guess you do not drive.  Cars have a "high" beam that points upwards/level and a "dipped" or low beam that points downwards, dipped downwards.  Simple!

Comment: Perhaps it has been mentioned elsewhere in this long thread of comments below, but my grandfather had some old cars in storage, and some of them (in addition to having a hand crank in front to start them) had headlights which had hinges which allowed for manual adjustment. So dipping may have in fact been a term which stems from the physical act of getting out and pointing them down...

Answer (score 5):

To be clear, the headlights of cars today usually have **two filaments**.

One filament projects the beam (off the mirrors behind) **straight ahead** (roughly level with the road, say).

The other one projects the beam (off the mirrors) **downwards** (ie dipped, pointing downwards).

Thus -- when the light is on normal (that is to say, "high" beam, because the beam is pointing up high), it hits the road a long way ahead.

In contrast, when you "dip" the lights, you will see the light shining on the road a fairly short distance ahead.

They are "dipped" ... **pointing-low** ... the beam is pointing downwards, rather than onwards.

The thing that you dip the lights with is called a "dip switch."

(Before the 60s they were a footswitch, now they are on a stalk, or obviously just automatic.)

Note that "dimming" the lights would not help, you would still dazzle the oncoming driver.  You must, of course, **point the beam downwards** - it's how headlights work.

I mention "bulbs have two filaments.." in the early days of motoring there were different systems to point the headlights downwards, when a car was oncoming..

> 'Dipping' (low beam) [ie low, downwards onto the ground] headlamps were introduced in 1915 by the Guide Lamp Company, but the 1917 Cadillac system allowed the light to be dipped with a lever inside the car rather than requiring the driver to stop and get out..." etc etc.

Dipping headlights, one of the basic elements of driving, along with brakes, turning indicators, etc!

*It would appear that using the word "dip" for dipping the headlights downwards, is now more BrE.  It seems that in the USA, the word has transformed to "dim." Moreover, people in the USA **tend to think of the downwards-dipped beam as the "normal" one**, and you then have "brights", "high" beam, etc.  Physically this is completely incorrect; dimming lights would achieve nothing, you have to literally point them downwards, i.e. dip them.*

Comment: I've never actually hear the phrase "dip switch" used in this context; it's generally "headlight switch" or "dimmer" or some such.  I'm not saying it's not correct, but - in general - if you hear the phrase "dip switch", the speaker is referring to a **[DIP switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIP_switch)**, where DIP stands for dual-inline-package.

Comment: Just incidentally!  I assumed that a "DIP switch" (computer electronics) is a catchy term because it's a funny play on the dip switch in a car!  Photo of a dip-switch .. http://www.mgb-stuff.org.uk/electricstext2.htm

Comment: @Joe You may want to note that on many vehicles, when the "high beams" are lit, they are lit *in addition to* the "low beams," thus earning them the commonly used title (in the US) of *brights* (as opposed to *dims*, which would indicate that only a single filament is lit). A simple [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=headlights+brights) should show its prominent use.  Furthermore, I question your assertion that the ability to drive and a technical comprehension of illumination technology are directly related.

Comment: @Joe Blow - 41, US, and I've driven for nearly 25 years.  DIP switches have been used for persistent settings in small electronics items - mostly things with radios in them, like remote controls and especially for garage doors - since the early 80s at least, and I've known and used the phrase since I was quite small.  As for the switch that dips the lights... in every car I've driven, the standard position **is** dipped, so that's the "high-beam" switch.  People who drive with their high beams on all the time, blinding oncoming traffic, are **dips**ts**.

Comment: @Joe... Finally, I would like to encourage you to be a little less scathing of fellow-users in your answers/comments.

Comment: In India, we usually say "Dim your headlights". Government even came out with a slogan, "Dim your light, save a life". And the switch which dims the headlight is called a dimmer.

Comment: I just did a quick, unscientific study: I searched eBay.com (US) for "dip switch."  I got 973 hits, of which 60 are headlight controllers; the rest are either garage-door openers, remote controls, or bulk DIP switches for electronics projects.  (Several of the headlight-part sellers are from the UK or India, btw.)  "Headlight dimmer switch" gets 1001 hits; "high beam switch" gets 208.

Comment: On eBay.co.uk, "dip switch" gets 646 hits: 312 in Vehicle Parts and Accessories, and 302 in Business, Office and Industrial.  "Headlight dimmer switch" gets 139 hits.  "High beam switch" gets 32.  As I said, totally unscientific, but it does indicate a Brit/Am variation...

Comment: @Joe - I've never really considered using eBay as a research tool, but now I've done it twice in one evening!  I see some bulbs advertised as 65W / 55W; most are advertised simply as 55W... so I suspect the answer is "it depends."  [This page at Osram/Sylvania](http://www.sylvania.com/ConsumerProducts/AutomotiveLighting/Products/Halogen/StandardHalogenProducts/) doesn't shed much light <g> on dual wattages, but does list some separate bulbs for high and low beams.  I'd forgotten that - all my cars for many years now have taken a single bulb per side.

Comment: @Joe - I think it may be a matter of where one lives.  I live now in Los Angeles; I have to drive a very long way out of the city to find an open section of road - it's considered not just rude but slightly reckless to use high beams where they can dazzle oncoming drivers (or shine in the rear-view mirror of the car ahead.)  Years ago, however, I lived in a very small town up in the mountains; the highway down to Sacramento was dark, deserted, and twisty, and you'd be a fool not to use your brights.  You'd dim them (or dip them!), however, as soon as you saw oncoming traffic.

Comment: +1 for that fascinating insight into a possible UK/US difference between 'normal' headlights. But you've always got to remember there are more US than UK English speakers - so in some ways, if usages differ, the US forms are arguably more 'standard' than UK. On the other hand, we have more *history* on our side of the pond. :)

Comment: @MT_Head: In case you didn't find out elsewhere (and in case it's either not given somewhere else on this page, or buried in the general verbiage), it's normal in the UK for dipped beam to be a lower-wattage filament than main beam. I imagine that would be the same in the US.

Comment: @Fumble - In the aftermarket, as I discovered in my eBay research, dual-wattage and single-wattage replacement lamps appear to be about equally prevalent - and then there are the cars with separate bulbs for low and high.  I don't know whether those are generally the same wattage or different, and I'm feeling too lazy to research it right now...

Answer (score 3):

Generally, dipping the lights means reducing headlight intensity and turning off the ones that aren't angled toward the ground.

Comment: Thanks! Does the word "dip" imply that, in English, everybody understands that the intensity of headlights is reduced by angling them toward the ground?

Comment: I speculate that, in the early days of motoring, your chauffeur would physically tilt the headlamps downwards when necessary. This constitutes dipping of the beam. All motorists trained in an English-speaking country will understand that "dipping" the headlights is performed in order to direct the beam away from oncoming drivers so as not to dazzle them - thus avoiding a few of the million or so deaths a year attributable to our favourite means of movement.

Comment: As a forty year old American motorist who learned to drive at age 12, I have NEVER heard this usage. I am wondering if I am an anomaly.

Comment: @horatio: We use *dim* in America, while the rest of the English-speaking world, especially Britain, happily uses *dip* :)

Comment: :) I see "Dip" signs everywhere  ( http://www.highwaytrafficsupply.com/images/regulatory_signs.html/W15-9.jpg ) and I always wonder how they knew I was coming.

Comment: Jez - I wonder why you say "Generally..."  of course dipping the lights means, well, dipping the lights.  Literally every extant vehicle made has this function.  BTW, I'm somewhat certain that in most cases the dipped (downwards-pointing) beams **are not less bright**.  Actually, they could be **a little brighter**. Finally, it's more a case of swapping between the two - I think you imply that the low-pointing ones stay on all the time.

Comment: FWIW I'll chime in as another American driver, driving for 33 years now, and have never heard the term "dip" when referring to headlights, while I've heard "dim" many, many times. Definitely not an American usage.

Comment: I'm Australian and wondered before reading the other answers if both "dip" and "dim" were in use, but for me "dip" is the winner and has no greater association with the early days of motoring than with the modern days since the crucial factor is the lowered angle of the headlight beams, not their brightness.

Comment: **"the crucial factor is the lowered angle of the headlight beams, not their brightness"** - indeed. That's all there is to it.